# PowerShell CSV line break but without changing the cell in the generated CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I get a list of users that I store in a variable that will then be used to create a CSV. Originally the elements of the variable were separated by a comma using `-join (",")`. I want the `","` to be replaced by a line break so I used `-join ("'n")` the line break is done well but the elements of the variable are not in the same cell.

This is what the CSV gives me:

[image: What I have]

Here is the desired result:

[image: What I want]

What I tried and it doesn't seem to work :

```
-join [Environment]::NewLine

ReplaceCommaWithNewLine($Compare -join ",")

$data = Get-Content -Path $Chemin_File_CSV                                                  
$data = $data -replace ",","`n"                                                         
$data | Set-Content -Path $Chemin_File_CSV                                                   
$data = Import-Csv -Path $Chemin_CSV_File
```

Do you know how to solve my problem ?

You can find the corresponding script below :

```
# Retrieving the list of privileged groups to check
$GroupsToCheck = @("Administrateurs","Administrateurs du schéma","Administrateurs de l’entreprise","Admins du domaine",       "Opérateurs de compte","Opérateurs de serveur" ,"Opérateurs de sauvegarde","Opérateurs d’impression")

# Retrieve the list of members of the AD group "Protected Users
$ADGroup_ProtectedUsers_Members = (Get-ADGroupMember "Protected Users").SamAccountName

# Comparison of the groups contained in the $GroupsToCheck table and in the AD group "Protected Users
$Compare = ((Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $GroupsToCheck  -DifferenceObject $ADGroup_ProtectedUsers_Members) | Where-Object -Property SideIndicator -EQ "<=").InputObject

# If $Compare is empty, Conform
if (!$Compare) {
    $Status = "Conform"
    $Value = $null

# Else, Not Conform
} else {
     $Status = "Non Conform"
     $Value=  ($Compare -join "`n")
}

$Path__CSV = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\test.csv"

$Content_CSV = (@"
"Status" ; "Value"
$Status  ; $Value
"@) | Out-File -FilePath $Path_CSV -Encoding UTF8 -Append
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot have line breaks. CSV will automatically create a new row if you try to add a line break in a cell.  CSV is a text file and does not have formatting like excel.  In excel you can get the desired results, but not in CSV.

Comment: @jdweng You can have multiline strings in CSV without a problem.

Comment: Pablo, please see my update re `,` vs. `;` (culture-specific field separator (delimiter))

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon : What I meant is you cannot have line breaks in a cell.

Comment: @jdweng define line break, because if by it you mean a LF character then mklement0's answer is clearly showing it is possible. At which point I would recommend you to remove your initial comment because its misleading.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon : What I said is correct.  The OP said he wanted to remove the commas in a cell and just have a new line.  Adding a new line in a cell will give the results that the OP did not want.  Look at the differences in the pictures the OP provided.

Comment: @jdweng OP's desired result is a cell with a multi-line string which can be accomplished by joining elements of an array with a LF characters as mklement0's answer is showing. In any case, I don't like wasting time in a pointless argument when its clearly not going anywhere

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon : What makes you think mkelement0's answer will really work?

Comment: @jdweng, what makes you think that mklement0's (note: no "e" after "mk") answer _won't_ work? Instead of making vague insinuations, try to provide specific arguments and/or evidence.

Comment: @mklement0 : I may look like it works, but in most applications you will not get the columns to align like in the OPs picture.  CSV is text with no formatting and you are trying to add formatting.

Comment: @jdweng, no one is trying to add formatting. Fields are added that have _embedded newlines_, which CSV supports. How this _data_ is later _formatted_ is a separate matter. As you can see, the raw text representation isn't helpful to the human observer, but visualizing the data via Excel or Numbers (on macOS), for instance, is, as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Pablo, you briefly posted a comment about the answer not working, which I suspect was due to the need for `-UseCulture` or `-Delimiter ';'`, as the answer now explains. If something is still not working, please provide feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use plain-text processing; create *objects* ([`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject)), which you can pass to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv).

```
[pscustomobject] @{
  Status = $Status
  Value = $Value
} | # see note re -UseCulture and -Delimiter at the bottom
  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 $Path_CSV -Append
```

`Export-Csv` automatically takes care of enclosing multi-line strings in `"..."`, which preserves their embedded newlines as part of the field (column) value (in fact, *all* fields are enclosed in `"..."`)<sup>[1]</sup>, as the following example with its in-memory equivalent, [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv), demonstrates:

```
[pscustomobject] @{
  SomeColumn = 42
  MultiLineColumn = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' -join "`n"
} | 
  ConvertTo-Csv
```

Output:

```
"SomeColumn","MultiLineColumn"
"42","foo
bar
baz"
```

Note:

- If your CSV format uses a *culture-specific* field separator in lieu of `,` - such as `;` - add `-UseCulture` to your `Export-Csv` / `ConvertTo-Csv` calls, assuming the desired separator is the one associated with the *current culture*.
- If you want to control the field separator (delimiter) explicitly, use the `-Delimiter` parameter.

---

<sup>[1] This is *invariably* true in *Windows PowerShell*, and true *by default* in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), where you now get to control the quoting behavior via the `-UseQuotes` and `-QuoteFields` parameters.</sup>